# Setting up a SQL Server cluster for the first time, some questions!

Tags: sql-server, clustering

I am a SharePoint architect but looking to implement AOAG with SharePoint in an Azure lab environment.

I'm building the first node in a cluster and I'm a little confused:

- I have my cluster object in AD, the installation asks me for a network name for SQL Server. What's the difference between this and the cluster object name?
- Likewise, also the cluster resource group name.
- Lastly, what's the IP address specified for?

Answer (score 0):

The network name is a virtual client access point for the instance of SQL Server on the failover cluster, and it needs to be unique on the domain.  This will be how you will connect to the instance.

The Cluster resource group is the name by which everything is grouped in the Windows Failover Cluster Manager, you will typically want this named similarly to what you named the instance.

The IP you provide will be tied to the network name you provided and needs to be unique as well.